# iAds mess up my screen drawing?

Tags: iphone, ios, iad

I have a universal iPhone/iPad app that I'm in the process of completing.  This is a music listening app that connects to and allows you to listen to music off of a user composed music site.

Since the user base for this app will be very small I've decided to put iAds in to try and get a little recovery on the programming costs.

The app is xib-less meaning that I create all components and draw every view manually.  I have all of the code in place to place the iAd on screen and off screen for its various states.  My app supports all rotations of all devices and my screens correctly reposition all components for every possible orientation.

After digging deep in the documentation I found that Apple always displays tapped on iAds in portrait mode.  If my device is in portrait mode (upright) then there is no problem.  However if I'm in landscape or upside down (yes it makes sense for this app), then the iAd displays in portrait but when closed my app is a mess.

The best way I can describe it is that each of my display items has a frame which I manually set to position it where I want it for each orientation.  This works perfectly until the user taps on an iAd.  The modal iAd dialog comes up then after it is closed even if I force a reposition of my components nothing draws correctly.

I've checked the view frame coordinates before and after the ad and I see some minor shifting.  But what is so strange is that my components even when forced to their frame locations I desire are just a mess.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Here is a link to the screen movie incase
embedding doesn't work:  http://www.screencast.com/t/1pSwUI3EiMF

Comment: I think you might have to post some of your code.

Comment: (1) Do you use Singleton design pattern to controlling iAd in your app?

Comment: (2) Do you use this line of code to force the iAd stay at the bottom of the screen: [self.adBanner setAutoresizingMask: 
       UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | 
       UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | 
       UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin];

Comment: Hello guys... I figured this one out.  Sorry to have wasted your time and bandwidth.  The issue was an underlaying view that really wasn't needed.   Bascially I had  Window->View->View->all of my controls.  The first "View" was the result of a cut/paste problem.  Once I removed it the issue went away!  Thanks!

Comment: GADBannerView's presentingViewController when it's an iAD also calls this, via ADInterstitialAd but it's hard to tell without reading the docs, which tells you to very subtle "Create a view controller and use it". Never would have guessed, I kept scouring google's documentation insetad. Thanks for posting this to hint it's subtler than I anticipated